# how to calculate geofence radius using jquery in google map API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

I want to calculate distance between 2 markers in geofence using jquery and I have to restrict distance to 5 km.
How to do it using jquery if I am getting latitude and longitude.
My Code to place markers on map is like this:

```
function addPoint(event) { //alert(document.getElementById("<%= Checkbox_Polygon.ClientID %>").checked);
    if (document.getElementById("chkDrawPolyGon").checked) {
      $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        clearMarkerData();
      })

      if (markers.length > 19) {
        alert("Maximum 20 points per poygon only");
      } else {
        path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);


        //alert(event.latLng);
        //alert(path.length);
        //alert(path.getLength());
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map,
          draggable: true
        });
        //alert(marker.getPosition());
        markers.push(marker);

        marker.setTitle("#" + path.length);
        //to get Position of marker
        alert(markers[0].position.lat() + ',' + markers[0].position.lng());

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (document.getElementById("chkDrawPolyGon").checked) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
            markers.splice(i, 1);
            path.removeAt(i);
            updatemarkerdata();
          }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
          if (document.getElementById("chkDrawPolyGon").checked) {
            for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
            path.setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
            updatemarkerdata();
          }

        });

        updatemarkerdata();
        //alert(markerdata);
        getMarkerData();
      }
    }
```

[I have markers here..
in this 1)i want to calculate distance between 2 marker. 2)Calucate radius if it is more than 3 points.the radius should be less than 5 kms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIIC8.png)

[With 3 markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EttVm.png)

Comment: Duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Comment: Do you want to add a Polygon or a Marker on the map?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Which two markers do you need to compute the distance between?  What do you want to do if it is greater than 5 km?

Comment: @Joyson I want to add a polygonal region.and its region must be between 5 kms

Comment: @geocodezip i want to compute distance between any to conjugate points . it will form a polygonal region right, with 3 markers atlest?
if it is greater than 5 kms have to pop up  a alert.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip i have added 2 images Which i think would provide description.
please suggest a way